# What’s the difference between the “wairole” and “role” attributes?

Tags: html, dojo, accessibility, wai-aria

I have begun doing dojo accessibility testing on a web application and have noticed that elements have both a role and a wairole attribute that seem to be the same value.

After much searching I have been unable to understand the difference between the two. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a full explanation, but the `role` attribute in the now abandoned XHTML2 had a much wider use than just the WAI-ARIA roles that are allowed for the `role` attribute in HTML5.

The was some suggestion ~2006/2007 that to avoid confusion, the attribute in HTML5 should be called `wairole`, and it may be that Dojo is just trying to cover both bases.

See http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2006-August/007150.html for one place where the `wairole` name was suggested.

Answer (score 5):

wairole attribute is no longer used. Use role as per WAI-ARIA 1.0 and [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/wai-aria.html#wai-aria)